# Recursive calculation is very slow

Tags: performance-tuning, recursion, geometry

I've got a recursive definition of Arcs that shares equal length and a several other dependencies to each respective predecessor.  (Imagine a book being bent.)

I formulated all necessary things here:

```
Pa[n_] := {d1 (0.5 + n), 0}
Pb[n_] := Pa[n] + R[n]*{1 - Cos[alpha[n]], Sin[alpha[n]]}
Pc[n_] := Pb[n - 1] + d2*{Cos[alpha[n - 1]], -Sin[alpha[n - 1]]}
R[n_] := Piecewise[{{(-Pa[n][[1]]^2 + 2*Pa[n][[1]]*Pc[n][[1]] - 
             Pc[n][[1]]^2 - Pc[n][[2]]^2)/
          (2*(Pa[n][[1]] - Pc[n][[1]])), n > 0}, {R0, n == 0}}]
M[n_] := {R[n] + Pa[n][[1]], 0}
alpha[n_] := len/R[n]
```

When I plot it up to order of 3, it takes a while, but it works.

```
Manipulate[
 Evaluate[
  Show[
   Graphics[
    Table[Circle[M[i], R[i], {Pi - alpha[i], Pi}], {i, 0, 3}]
    ],
   PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {0, len*1.2}},
   Frame -> True
   ]
  ],
 {{R0, 10000}, 0, 10000},
 {{len, 70}, 0, 500},
 {{d1, 4.3}, 0, 20},
 {{d2, 13}, 0, 20}
 ]
```

What can I do to make it calculate really fast for order 3 and higher?

Comment: At least look [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html).

Comment: It might help to look up "Functions That Remember Values They Have Found" in the documentation.

Comment: @march Thanks for the hint. Unfortunately, this does not seem to help, at least not inside the Manipulate[]-environment.

In addition, I'd really like to understand, why it is necessary to Evaluate[] the Show[], to have it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it work.

Remembering function values is one key, but I needed another one: a Module

```
arc[mn_, mR0_, mlen_, md1_, md2_] := 
 Module[{n = mn, Pa, Pb, Pc, R, M, alpha, R0 = mR0, len = mlen, 
   d1 = md1, d2 = md2}, 
  Pa[n_] := Pa[n] = {d1*(0.5 + n), 0}; 
  Pb[n_] := Pb[n] = Pa[n] + R[n]*{1 - Cos[alpha[n]], Sin[alpha[n]]}; 
  Pc[n_] := Pc[n] = Pb[n - 1] + d2*{Cos[alpha[n - 1]], -Sin[alpha[n - 1]]};    
  R[n_]  := R[n] = 
    Piecewise[{{(-Pa[n][[1]]^2 + 2*Pa[n][[1]]*Pc[n][[1]] - 
          Pc[n][[1]]^2 - Pc[n][[2]]^2)/(2*(Pa[n][[1]] - Pc[n][[1]])), 
       n > 0}, {R0, n == 0}}]; 
  M[n_]  := M[n] = {R[n] + Pa[n][[1]], 0}; 
  alpha[n_] := alpha[n] = len/R[n]; 

  Circle[M[n], R[n], {Pi - alpha[n], Pi}]
  ]
```

and then:

```
 Manipulate[
     Evaluate[
      Show[
       Graphics[
        Table[arc[i, R0, len, d1, d2], {i, 0, n}]
        ],
       PlotRange -> {{0, n*d1 + len}, {-20, len*1.2}},
       Frame -> True
       ]
      ],
     {{n, 3}, 0, 20, 1},
     {{R0, 10000}, 0, 10000},
     {{len, 70}, 0, 500},
     {{d1, 4.3}, 0, 20},
     {{d2, 13}, 0, 20}
     ]
```